# Is const double cast at compile time?

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point

It makes sense to define mathematical constants as double values but what happens when one requires float values instead of doubles? Does the compiler automatically interpret the doubles as floats at compile-time (so they are actually treated as they were const floats) or is this conversion made at runtime?

Comment: Any sensible compiler will do conversions of constants at compile time.

Comment: Well, my experience shows that there are also compilers out there that are not sensible :P  So to be sure to avoid run-time conversions, better use the right type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "defining", you mean using `#define`, here's what happens:

Say you have:

```
#define CONST1 1.5
#define CONST2 1.12312455431461363145134614  // Assume some number too
                                             // precise for float
```

Now if you have:

```
float x = CONST1;
float y = CONST2;
```

you don't get any warning for `x` because the compiler automatically makes `CONST1` a `float`. For `y`, you get a warning because `CONST2` doesn't fit in a `float`, **but** the compiler casts it to `float` anyway.

---

If by "defining", you mean using `const` variables, here's what happens:

Say you have

```
const double CONST1=1.5;
const double CONST2=1.12312455431461363145134614; // Assume some number too
                                                  // precise for float
```

Now if you have:

```
float x = CONST1;
float y = CONST2;
```

there is no way for the compiler to know the values of `CONST1` and `CONST2`(*) and therefore cannot interpret the values as `float` at compile them. You will be given two warnings about possible loss of data and the conversion will be done at runtime.

(*) Actually there is a way. Since the values are `const`, the optimizer may decide not to take a variable for them, but replace the values throughout the code. This could get complicated though, as you may pass the address to these variables around, so the optimizer may decide not to do that. That is, don't count on it.

---

Note that, this whole thing is true for any basic type conversions. If you have

```
#define CONST3 1
```

then you think `CONST3` is `int`, but if you put it in a `float`, it would become `float` at compile-time, or if you put it in a `char`, it would become `char` at compiler-time.

Comment: “there is no way for the compiler to know the values of CONST1 and CONST2” – as you noted yourself, this is just blatantly false. In fact, the compiler *does* know, and does optimise. You *can* (and should – why not?) count on it in well-defined circumstances.

Comment: And you're sure the precision of `float` is sufficient for `1.2` to be represented exactly? ;)

Comment: I definitely dont want to use preprocessor macros in my code. The question here is whether common compilers like g++ or vc do these optimizations or not. I even thought of inline functions but i dislike the idea of "calling" in order to get a constant.

Comment: @Paranaix: how expensive do you think double->float conversion is? It's "just" a reduction in precision, it's unlikely to have measurable overhead on top of a copy.

Comment: @ChristianRau, you got me there ;)

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I am not so certain on that, so I didn't want to give bad information. Although it seems to me that the compiler can't eliminate the variable altogether (simply because you can get a pointer to it).

Comment: @Paranaix, defining a constant with `#define` is not a sin.

Comment: @SteveJessop, exactly. Besides, don't most FPUs work on `double` (or even `long double`) anyway, so using `float` is in fact less fast? (Or am I wrong there?)

Comment: @Shahbaz while the compiler must still provide the variable so you can take a pointer to it, it can freely assume that the value never changes since it is defined as "const". (and if someone takes a pointer to it, casts away the const-ness, changes the value, and expects this to somehow "work", they deserve what they get)

Comment: @araqnid, yes of course. Any decent optimizer will do it, but the compiler by default doesn't do it. To back up what I'm saying, the code generated by gcc for a 15 line test program didn't substitute the constant, although with -O2 it even precomputed the function having the constant as parameter. So what I'm saying is, you cannot say it will ALWAYS be substituted at compile time.